# SQLite command to add index to the history tables

Tags: sqlite, firefox

What are the SQLite commands to add an index to both the `moz_historyvisits` and `moz_places` tables in the `places.sqlite` file in the Mozilla profile folder?

Answer (score 0):

The default index definitions for these tables look like this:

```
CREATE INDEX moz_historyvisits_dateindex ON moz_historyvisits (visit_date);
CREATE INDEX moz_historyvisits_fromindex ON moz_historyvisits (from_visit);
CREATE INDEX moz_historyvisits_placedateindex ON moz_historyvisits (place_id, visit_date);
CREATE INDEX moz_places_faviconindex ON moz_places (favicon_id);
CREATE INDEX moz_places_frecencyindex ON moz_places (frecency);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX moz_places_guid_uniqueindex ON moz_places (guid);
CREATE INDEX moz_places_hostindex ON moz_places (rev_host);
CREATE INDEX moz_places_lastvisitdateindex ON moz_places (last_visit_date);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX moz_places_url_uniqueindex ON moz_places (url);
CREATE INDEX moz_places_visitcount ON moz_places (visit_count);
```

Comment: great, just don't know where to put my values. Clarification would be great for my lack of understanding. Thanks. =)

Comment: Please clarify your question.